# Mitigation of lattice-based KEM decryption failure possibility

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, hybrid-encryption, kem

Lattice-based PQC KEM has small probability of decryption failure

In an offline setting it can be catastrophic despite being improbable.

Proposed mitigation:

```
let latice1 and latice2 be two separate instances of the same kyber scheme
lt1pk: lattice1 private key
lt2pk: lattice2 private key
generate entropy string SS
generate entropy string lss1
generate entropy string lss2
len(SS) = len(lss1) = len(lss2) = kyber_ss_len
lt1ct: lattice1.encapsulate(lss1)
lt2ct: lattice2.encapsulate(lss2)
attach (lss1 XOR SS) to lt1ct
attach (lss2 XOR SS) to lt2ct
recipient can now use either lt1pk+lt1ct+(lss1 XOR SS) or the same from lattice2 to recover SS.
```

Are there any problems with this approach or is there a better one?

Rationale for using lss1 and lss2 is to avoid building a relationship between lt1ct and lt2ct by encapsulating the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't encrypting multiple messages achieve what you're trying to do as well? The ciphertext is randomized by some noise and two ciphertext should have different noise vectors. Encryption the same message two or more times should reduce the probability that all of them fail to decrypt. This way you don't need multiple keys.

Comment: ultimately, the SS string goes into a ow-PRF to be mixed with other SS strings from other KEM and ECC-DH schemes.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid decryption failures, it can be done (easily) by inflating parameters.
This is to say that if you have certain settings where they *must* be avoided, this is easy to accomplish.

At a high level, analyzing decryption failures in lattice-based KEMs (tends) to reduce to analyzing

$$\lVert \vec e_0^t \vec s+ \vec e_1^t \vec r+ e\rVert_\infty \stackrel{?}{\leq} q/2p$$

These random variables are (at a high level --- much of the below is *slightly* scheme dependent)

Here, $\vec e_0, \vec e_1\sim \chi_e^n$ for some error distribution $\chi_e$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\vec r, \vec s\sim \chi_s^n$ for an error distribution $\chi_s$.

Anyway, what people *typically* do is

1. explicitly compute the distribution of$\vec e_0^t\vec s + \vec e_1^t\vec r+e$. See [Vadim Lybushavesky's notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTdW5ryznp-dUBBjN12QbvWz9R41NDGU/view?usp=sharing) for a sample computation, I believe in section 2.
2. Choose the scheme parameters $q, p$ such that the above inequality is violated with exponentially small probability.

One can avoid this second step though --- provided $\chi_e, \chi_s$ have finite support (this can always be made to occur), then one can instead compute the *support* of this aforementioned distribution, and choose $q/2p$ such that the above inequality is *never* violated.

If you are particularly concerned with decryption failures, parameterize your scheme to avoid them (or use a scheme that is already parameterized to not have them --- I believe an NTRU variant submitted to NIST was of this form, perhaps NTRU prime).
This is *much* easier to do than to jerry-rig some ad-hoc solution on top of the underlying scheme.

Comment: Hi Mark, I was reading the  section 2.3.2 Bounding the Total Error, 
I am not able to understand it the example in this section 
Could you please explain it for me ?

Comment: @DonFreecs it is generally considered better etiquette to do such a thing in a separate question, as it makes searching for the discussion later easier.

Answer (score 0):

This places potentially dangerous information in the hands of the attacker and significantly reduces the efficiency of Kyber.

Cryptographically speaking, the biggest worry is that your scheme would allow an attacker to recover lss1 XOR lss2 by XORing the attachments. I cannot immediately think of a means to combine this information with the Kyber encapsulation scheme to recover one or the other, but this seriously reduces the joint entropy of lss1 and lss2 for the attacker.

More definitively, your scheme doubles the bandwidth required to share public keys, more than doubles the bandwidth to share cryptograms, trebles the entropy requirement to establish a key, and doubles the encryption time. All of these undermine the efficiencies that make Kyber such a desirable candidate.

The reencrypt-on-failure approach retains the efficiencies as it will almost never be invoked in practice. The threat now is active probing of failure cases by an adversary, which modern lattice schemes already defend against. Note that your scheme is not immune from failure probing as adversaries could choose two different values SSS and SSS' then forming lss1 XOR SSS and lss2 XOR SSS' with lss1 more prone to failure and then determine whether SSS or SSS' were used by the recipient in future communications.

Comment: But lss1 and lss2 are independent entropy strings. I omitted a keyed permutation step here because you have a OTP situation. Reencrypt-on-failure is not an option in an offline setting as stated in the question. Efficiency is not a concern, quantum resistance is.